Meta Pixel PageView event
The PageView event is mentioned in many examples on Facebook developer pages (e.g.), but it is not listed on the official standard events list. I have not been able to find it mentioned on any other official documentation pages, except within examples.
Is PageView a standard event of Meta Pixel and Meta Conversions API? If it is, is there any explicit official documentation to support this, or is the only reason to use it because it appears in examples?

Any updates on this?

A PageView is called "ViewContent" in Meta.
From the docs:

A visit to a web page you care about (for example, a product page or landing page). ViewContent tells you if someone visits a web page's URL, but not what they see or do on that page.
A person lands on a product details page.

Here is an example request:
"data": [
    {
        "event_name": "ViewContent",
        "event_time": 1733749798,
        "event_id": "event.id.123",
        "event_source_url": "http:\/\/jaspers-market.com",
        "user_data": {
            "client_ip_address": "1.2.3.4",
            "client_user_agent": "test user agent"
        }
    }
]

